# Python JSONPath Filter expressions error, Unexpected character for jsonpath-rw 1.4.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, jsonpath

I installed jsonpath-rw 1.4.0 with

`sudo apt-get install python-jsonpath-rw`

which comes with a `/usr/bin/jsonpath`. But that is giving me errors when using Filter expressions:

```
$ jsonpath '$..book[?(@.price < 10)]' book.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jsonpath", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('jsonpath-rw==1.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'jsonpath.py')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/bin/jsonpath.py", line 71, in entry_point
    main(*sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/bin/jsonpath.py", line 57, in main
    expr = parse(args.expression)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/parser.py", line 14, in parse
    return JsonPathParser().parse(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/parser.py", line 32, in parse
    return self.parse_token_stream(lexer.tokenize(string))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/parser.py", line 55, in parse_token_stream
    return new_parser.parse(lexer = IteratorToTokenStream(token_iterator))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 1061, in parseopt_notrack
    lookahead = get_token()     # Get the next token
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/parser.py", line 179, in token
    return next(self.iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/lexer.py", line 33, in tokenize
    t = new_lexer.token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ply/lex.py", line 393, in token
    newtok = self.lexerrorf(tok)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jsonpath_rw/lexer.py", line 165, in t_error
    raise JsonPathLexerError('Error on line %s, col %s: Unexpected character: %s ' % (t.lexer.lineno, t.lexpos - t.lexer.latest_newline, t.value[0]))
jsonpath_rw.lexer.JsonPathLexerError: Error on line 1, col 8: Unexpected character: ?
```

So does jsonpath-rw 1.4.0 not support Filter expressions?

It seems to be [working fine according to this blog post](http://blog.ingensol.pl/2015/03/need-to-make-quick-json-fixes-jsonpath.html), but that's in 2015.

Has things changed since then?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm hitting the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Mike. I'm glad that it is not only me. I haven't get around to look into it yet, and most probably it will never happen. Would you be able to log a bug there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this working by using `jsonpath-rw-ext` instead of `jsonpath-rw`. This seems to be the one that has support for the filter extensions.

Comment: If you're using the `jsonpath-ng` library, then `import jsonpath_ng.ext` and use `jsonpath_ng.ext.parse(...)` instead of `jsonpath_ng.parse(...)`

Comment: @ArthurHebert-Ryan Thanks, I just needed that :)